# Enable LED Torch for IOS App Alerts (Without enabling in iPhone System Settings)

Tags: iphone, ios, background, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

So here's my problem: I have alerts come from my app fairly often. I've made it so they have a custom ring and vibration for when the alerts come. I want to be able to make their LED light flash on alerts as well.

I've set it up so that if these alerts come when the app is in the foreground, the LED flash and ring/vibrate work perfectly fine. However, if an alert comes when the app is in the background, I am only able to have the ring/vibrate work.

I don't want the user to have to enable it in the iPhone system settings to get LED flash alerts from all apps. I have used the inAppSettingsKit and added a settings preference for whether or not the user wants LED flash alerts. But even though my LED alert methods are called in the background, the LED does not actually flash. Is this because Apple does not allow you to control the LED unless your using it in the foreground? Does anyone know of a workaround?

Here's the simplest part of where I have it turned on and off. I control this with different timers and notification methods. The timers and notifications are called in the background the same way they are in the foreground, however the LED just doesn't turn on in the background.

```
AVCaptureDevice *torched=[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        [torched lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [torched setTorchMode:YES];
        [torched setFlashMode:YES];
        [torched unlockForConfiguration];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the "LED" you're referring to the camera flash?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the 'torch' version. I'll add part of my code above. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, my guess is that you're right about Apple not allowing you to control the LED unless your app is in the foreground, as some users won't want their flash going off sometimes. That's not based on fact; just an opinion/guess.

Comment: Yeah, I'll let you know if I find a workaround. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. There are applications/tweaks in the Cydia store for jailbroken devices that allow lock screen access to the torch, but I'm not sure if they're accessing private APIs and such.